# How do I delete "Documents & Data" from iCloud?

Tags: icloud, privacy, macos

Apple currently has two types of storage in iCloud:

1. iCloud Drive, for Macs running Yosemite.
2. Documents & Data, for Macs running Mavericks or earlier.

I have one Mac running Mavericks, and the other running Yosemite, and I have upgraded to iCloud Drive. Does that mean that my data in (2) above is **moved** to (1), or that it's **copied**?

My goal is to delete all data stored in both (1) and (2). I deleted all my data from (1). Does it mean that all data stored in (2) is also deleted? If not, how do I delete all my data from (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, once you migrate to iCloud Drive, your old 'Documents & Data' storage is converted & no longer exists in its old location.

Mavericks/iOS 7 can't see iCloud Drive & Yosemite/iOS 8 can't see the old Documents & Data, migrated or not.

Refs:

- http://support.apple.com/en-la/HT201104
- http://support.apple.com/en-la/HT201385
- http://www.cultofmac.com/296334/psa-shouldnt-upgrade-icloud-drive-ios-8-yet/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/203304/everything-you-need-to-know-about-using-icloud-drive-and-icloud-photo-library/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Tetsujin. Do you have a reference for "no longer exists in its old location"? Neither of the documents you linked to says so explicitly. I found only a statement that "Any documents that you've already stored in iCloud are automatically moved to iCloud Drive when you upgrade" which seems to mean that they no longer exist in their old location, but I can't find anything confirming that.

Comment: Various sources - http://www.cultofmac.com/296334/psa-shouldnt-upgrade-icloud-drive-ios-8-yet/ … http://www.howtogeek.com/203304/everything-you-need-to-know-about-using-icloud-drive-and-icloud-photo-library/ all say once you've converted it - & it IS a conversion, takes minutes to hours, depending on size - there's no going back. Warning pic added to Answer...

Comment: I second Tetsujin's beliefs here. In truth, you really have no way to know if or when the old data gets purged from Apple's servers. They likely exist in some form of server backups but also likely are no longer linkable to your Apple account. Apple has a long history of not wanting to know who owns what customer data, deleting it promptly from the live servers and ensuring that engineering won't record who placed what file in the cloud once you delete it from a device or accept a migration to a new version of the service. Also, bugs could defy their best intentions.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to Apple support, and they confirmed what was said in the accepted answer -- when you upgrade from "Documents & Data" to "iCloud Drive", the data is moved, not copied. Hence, deleting your data from iCloud Drive means that it's gone from both locations on Apple servers.